# Spark foeach no effect on Java Map

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to iterate through a DataSet in Apache Spark 2.1 and I have this method that goes through all the rows in a foreach and what I want to do is to have a Java map where the activity is the key and an array of minutes in a day contains how often that activity occured in that particular minute in all days, but due to the way Spark works it will not work like this. How can I make the following code so that I can get a map or a dataset with each activity having the number of occurences of each minute(an occurence of a minute is between the startMinuteInDay and period + startMinuteInDay.

```
def make_frequencies(dataset: Dataset[Row]): java.util.HashMap[String, Array[Int]] = {
  var freq_map = new java.util.HashMap[String, Array[Int]]
  val activities = List("Sleeping", "Toileting", "Showering", "Snack", "Breakfast", "Leaving","Grooming","Spare_Time/TV","Lunch","Dinner")

  for(a <- activities){
    freq_map.put(a, new Array[Int](1440))
  }
  dataset.foreach(r => {
    val period = r.getDouble(2).toInt
    val startMinInDay = r.getDouble(3).toInt
    val activity = r.getString(4)
    println(" period " + r.getDouble(2) + " activity "+r.getString(4))

    var i = startMinInDay
    val end = startMinInDay + period
    print()
    while(i <= end && i < 1440){
      freq_map.get(activity)(i) += 1
      i+=1
    }
  })
  freq_map
}
```

Comment: Can you show how your dataset look like ?

Comment: My dataset has the following columns: startMinute(integer), endMinute(integer), period(double), startminuteInDay(Double) and activity(String).